# Comparing matrices of different size in matlab and storing values that are close

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have two matrices A and B. A(:,1) corresponds to an x-coordinate, A(:,2) corresponds to a y-coordinate, and A(:,3) corresponds to a certain radius. All three values in a row describe the same circle. Now let's say...

A =

[1,4,3]

[8,8,7]

[3,6,3]

B =

[1,3,3]

[1, 92,3]

[4,57,8]

[5,62,1]

[3,4,6]

[9,8,7]

What I need is to be able to loop through matrix A and determine if there are any rows in matrix B that are "similar" as in the x value is within a range (-2,2) of the x value of A (Likewise with the y-coordinate and radius).If it satisfies all three of these conditions, it will be added to a new matrix with the values that were in A. So for example I would need the above data to return...

ans =

[1,4,3]

[8,8,7]

Please help and thank you in advance to anyone willing to take the time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ismembertol](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html).

```
result = A(ismembertol(A,B,2,'ByRows',1,'DataScale',1),:)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Manual method

```
A = [1,4,3;
     8,8,7;
     3,6,3];
B = [1,3,3;
     1,92,3;
     4,57,8;
     5,62,1;
     3,4,6;
     9,8,7]; % example matrices
t = 2;       % desired threshold
m = any(all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, permute(B, [3 2 1])))<=t, 2), 3);
result = A(m,:);
```

The key is using [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to move the first dimension of `B` to the third dimension. Then [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) computes the element-wise differences for all pairs of rows in the original matrices. A row of `A` should be selected if [`all`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) the absolute differences with respect to [`any`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) column of `B` are less than the desired threshold `t`. The resulting variable `m` is a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) which is used for selecting those rows.

#### Using `pdist2` (Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox)

```
m = any(pdist2(A, B, 'chebychev')<=t, 2);
result = A(m,:);
```

Ths [`pdist2`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function with the `chebychev` option computes the maximum coordinate difference ([Chebychev distance](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), or [L<sub>∞</sub> metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions)) between pairs of rows.

Answer (score 0):

## With for loop

It should work:

```
A = [1,4,3;
     8,8,7;
     3,6,3]
B = [1,3,3;
     1,92,3;
     4,57,8;
     5,62,1;
     3,4,6;
     9,8,7]
index = 1;
for i = 1:size(A,1) 
  C = abs(B - A(i,:));
  if any(max(C,[],2)<=2)
    out(index,:) = A(i,:);
    index = index + 1
  end
end
```

For each row of A, computes the absolute difference between B and that row, then checks if there exists a row in which the maximum is less than 2.

## Without for loop

```
ind = any(max(abs(B - permute(A,[3 2 1])),[],2)<=2);
out = A(ind(:),:);
```

Comment: This seems to have just returned matrix A as it is. Also I do want to to not that the matrices I am working with are much larger, A and B were just examples. In my actual script A is a 628 x 3 matrix and B is a 1200 x 3 matrix

Comment: Which method seems to just return matrix A?

Comment: Ok I found, actually it was not returning A, but the correct result with some unnecessary `[0 0 0]` due to `out(i,:)` (hence its number of rows was depending on the last row in A that fulfilled the condition).
Anyway, I suggest you to use @rahnema1 answer, that is using a built-in function and has the better computation time regarding to other answers proposed.